# Settings Karma to run tests with jasmine, requirejs and react

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm working on creation my own [bootstrap project](https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap) which includes RequireJS for modules structure, Backbone for routing and simple static views, ReactJS for components. The project works fine, but I want to add unit-testing support to cover my units of code in future projects. I'm trying to add Karma as a test runner with Jasmine and RequireJS support in unit tests (then I'll add [TestUtils](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) for components testing).

At the moment I have some troubles with Karma... it not works for me...
I created Gruntfile.js with configuration for karma:

```
karma: {
    unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.config.js'
    }
}
```

Also I added [`karma.config.js`](https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/karma.config.js) file with configurations. And also I added the file with RequireJS configurations for tests [`test-main.js`](https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/spec/test-main.js)

But I'm got the troubels when trying to run tests with command `grunt test`:

```
grunt test

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
14 12 2015 15:06:17.594:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
14 12 2015 15:06:17.634:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/
14 12 2015 15:06:17.644:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
14 12 2015 15:06:18.849:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket Gvi8xqI0lfbPEEOGAAAA with id 60807377
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.013 secs / 0 secs)
```

And on this message programm is stuck... Have someone useful advices???

PS: I used this tutorial to use RequireJS with Karma tests: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html

Comment: I checked versions and found newest tutorial for using Karma and RequireJS on official site: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html.

But it's still not works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `karma.config.js`

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'bower_components/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'spec/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
    'spec/test-main.js'
],

exclude: [
    'scripts/main.js'
],

frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

plugins: ['karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-requirejs', 'karma-jasmine'],
```

Run from command line:

```
npm install requirejs --save-dev
```

In `spec/test-main.js`

```
var pathToModule = function (path) {
    console.log(path);
    return path.replace(/^spec\//, '../spec/').replace(/\.(js)$/, '');
};

...
allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(normalizedTestModule));
...

baseUrl: '/base/scripts',
```

and remove

```
urlArgs: ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I made these changes, but it's still not works for me. I'm got this error message:
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/scripts/spec/FirstSpec.js


PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Script error for "spec/FirstSpec"
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
  at c:/Users/dmytro.medvid/sites/evolution/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140

Comment: I commited all changes to the github repo: https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap . Grunt configurations located in Gruntfile.js, karma configuration in karma.config.js and test-main.js located in spec directory (spec/test-main.js). Looks like something wrong with spec files

Comment: I found the problem, I missed some things... Now all works!!! Your answer was is a very helpful!!! Thanks!